# extruding a mirrored object goes wrong

Tags: faces, mirror, extrude

[image]

so this how what happen when extruding my object to inside. The faces go inside as will which is completely the opposite of whats happening in the tutorial  here is the link https://youtu.be/QXNRrt8EcEg it start at minute 13  so what should i do

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It looks like you have selected the faces and extrude them. In the tutorial he selects only the top edge and extrudes it in.

Comment: i didnt understand ..so i should extrude  using the edges  not faces?

Comment: oh it worked thank you